# Creating equations for models. Computational Neuroscience

Tags: python, brian

How do you come up with the equations so you can create the reactions you want in Brian 2?

I understand this is essential to creating your model. I wanted to know if there are tips to this effect or to being better at Brian 2.

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/equations.html) would help you use the Brian2 properly to define a neuron but from the theoretical perspective and how they come up with this set of equations for neurons, you can read [NeuralDynamics](https://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/index.html) book or [Izhikevich](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/dynamical-systems-neuroscience) book.
In summary, Hodgkin and Huxley first came up with the equation that describes the membrane potential activity of a neuron back in 1952, and then other people started to reduce the complexity of the equation and its dimensionality for simulation purposes and other reasons that you can find in detail in above books.